# How to clean up this test using better Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am still getting my Ruby skills up to speed.

I have been trying to figure out if I can DRY out this code for an rspec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Role, type: :model do

    describe "has several roles types " do

        before :each do 
            @roles = Role.all
        end

        context "The role types that are valid" do
            it "includes 'proofreader', 'admin', 'super_admin' " do
                expect(@roles.any?{|r| r.name == 'proofreader'}).to be_truthy
                expect(@roles.any?{|r| r.name == 'admin'}).to be_truthy
                expect(@roles.any?{|r| r.name == 'super_admin'}).to be_truthy
            end
        end

        context "The role types that are not valid " do
            it "includes 'developer' " do
                expect(@roles.any?{|r| r.name == 'developer'}).to be_falsy
            end
        end

    end

end
```

Specifically I want to reduce those three lines of code down to one but it has eluded me how to check an ActiveRecord relation for three string values in one line.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `be true` instead of `be_truthy`. Please see the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you need to use `include` matcher:

```
it "includes 'proofreader', 'admin', 'super_admin' " do
  expect(@roles.map(&:name)).to include('proofreader', 'admin', 'super_admin')
end
```

Also, you can remove `before` block and just use `Role.pluck(:name)` instead:

```
let(:roles_names) { Role.pluck(:name) }
it '...' do
  expect(roles_names).to include('proofreader', 'admin', 'super_admin')
end
```

Comment: And note that `let` is the new `@`.

Comment: Thank you Ilya.  Very clear answer and I will also up vote for the 'let' and 'pluck' lesson.  Much appreciated.